# Why I am getting 400 Error on Ajax request

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress

I stuck while in the WP AJAX.

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: spaceajax.ajaxurl, // this have my admin ajax URL
    data: {
        "event_id"  : 1,
        "space_id"  : 1,
        "booking_id": 1,
        'action'    : 'requestContract'
    },
    success: function(result) {
        alert("Success!");
    }
});
```

in my functions.php

```
function requestContract(){
    echo "Checkpoint"; die; 
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_requestContract', 'requestContract' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_requestContract', 'requestContract' );
```

Now I am getting 400 Bad request error. Any guess what I am doing wrong?

Comment: 404 means `Not found`. are you getting `404` or `400`?

Comment: 400 Error (Bad Request)

Comment: If you wrap the data object in `JSON.stringify(dataObjectGoesHere)`, do you still get the error?

Comment: Did you try to send request with `postman` or similar tool to make sure that your server is responding ?

Comment: can you place some details of the error message you are getting? need some more information to help, and what is the action on backend? not the code just the action

Comment: 400 Bad Request indicates that the parameters you are passing to the URL are not valid. You are missing parameters or adding them when you shouldn't or the params are not formatted correctly. See -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/400

Comment: I am using the chrome browser. Its a jQuery ajax request

Comment: @AntihypeBird The website is working all pages are also working. Only issue with ajax.

Comment: @daddygames Thank You very much. It was the formatting issue of data parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to answer my own question. As [@daddygames](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3224608/daddygames) suggested 400 Bad request may come when the URL parameters are not correct. So I removed my formatting on the ajax request. This makes it working.

I am pasting the working code again for reference.

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: spaceajax.ajaxurl, // this have my admin ajax URL
    data: {
        "event_id":1,
        "space_id":1,
        "booking_id":1,
        'action':'requestContract'
    },
    success: function(result) {
        alert("Success!");
    }
});
```